# Append specified rows next to each other in a dataframe based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

Here is my sample table:

| ID | Code | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 23 | 1 | 4 |
| 123 | 23 | 2 | 6 |
| 124 | 24 | 2 | 7 |
| 125 | 25 | 37 | 9 |
| 123 | 24 | 75 | 6 |
| 124 | 24 | 49 | 11 |
| 124 | 25 | 43 | 12 |

I want to get this. **I need to sum up the values of Col2 and Col3 whenever Code for an ID repeats.**

| ID | Code | Col2_23 | Col3_23 | Col2_24 | Col3_24 | Col2_25 | Col3_25 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 23 | 3 | 10 | 75 | 6 | NaN | NaN |
| 124 | 24 | NaN | NaN | 51 | 18 | 43 | 12 |
| 125 | 25 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 37 | 9 |

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It looks something like `df.pivot_table(index=['ID', 'Code'], columns='Code', values=['Col2', 'Col3'])` but it's really unclear what `Col2` and `Col3` represent in the output dataframe. Why is the information duplicated in 25, but it's the first instance for 23 and 24? Is that just the first instance in each column regardless of whether or not it's covered in a later row?

Comment: Hi @HenryEcker, Col2 and Col3 are excessive. They should be removed, ideally. But even if they are present, it doesn't hurt my purpose.

Comment: @HenryEcker As for the duplicates, I have edited my table. I need to sum up the values of Col2 and Col3 whenever Code for an ID repeats.